# Laravel - Order By & Group By strange results

Tags: php, mysql, database, eloquent

**Setup:**

I'm trying to implement a pretty standard use-case of getting all of the conversations a user is a part of, and returning only the latest message from each conversation. I'd like to do this in a manner that allows me to use laravel's paginator.

But the group by command seems to be ignoring the order of the subquery! (whether the sort is ASC or DESC, the results are the same).

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id    body         user_id  recipient_id  conversation_id  created_at 
1     <p>test</p>  1        3             -1-3-            2019-10-06 20:00:00
2     <p>test</p>  1        3             -1-3-            2019-10-06 20:10:00
3     <p>test</p>  3        1             -1-3-            2019-10-06 20:20:00
4     <p>test</p>  2        1             -1-2-            2019-10-06 20:00:00
5     <p>test</p>  1        2             -1-2-            2019-10-06 20:10:00
6     <p>test</p>  1        2             -1-2-            2019-10-06 20:20:00
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

NOTE: I'm not worrying about the where clauses for filtering the data by the user yet.

**Attempts:**

```php
$conversations = Message::fromSub(function ($query) {
    $query->from('messages')
          ->orderBy('conversation_id')
          ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
}, 'm')->groupBy('conversation_id')->get();
```

```php
$conversations = DB::select(DB::raw("
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM messages
        ORDER BY `created_at` DESC
    ) AS R
    GROUP BY R.`conversation_id`
"));
```

I'm completely stumped :(

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but you can use it as a placeholder until someone submits a better answer    `select * from messages where id in (SELECT max(id) FROM messages group by conversation_id);`

Comment: Yes you are right Group by doesn't really care, that why You should name every cloumn and tell the group by what to do with the other column that are not grouped. what they should show see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: Thank you both! While it's not my favorite looking solution (because part of it still has a RAW call in it), it still seems to be working.
Using the example from @Dimi (which worked great as a raw query), and the cause pointed out by @nbk I was able to come up with an Eloquent equivalent that works for now:

```php
        $conversations = Message::select('*')->whereIn('id', function ($query) {
            $query->select(\DB::raw('max(id) as latest'))->from('messages')->groupBy('conversation_id');
        })->get();
```